# Offline login for ParseUser

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Is there anyway to save the `ParseUser` to phone so in the next time user can login without the network connection. I have checked the documentation at https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html but couldn't find anything about `saveEventually` or `pin` like the ParseObject. Currently I have to save the username and password separately (using `SharedPreference`) when in offline mode (no network connection) but it is not good since I do need the ParseUser object in order to save the relationship with the other entities.

The only solution I came up with for now is logging in the user again (in the background) using the sensitive data (username, password) stored in the `SharedPreference` in order to save the relationship whenever having the network. However, this way is not good in term of security since I have to store the password in the plain text in the `SharedPreference` in order to log in to Parse.

(a re-post from Parse Google Group. I have tore my hair for 2 days for this)

Answer (score 1):

You have to Use Shared Prefrences only. Save username and password in prefrences if it accepted by Parse User like this:

```
    mPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("cumulus",MODE_PRIVATE);
     uname = username.getText().toString();
        pass = password.getText().toString();

         ParseUser.logInInBackground(uname, pass,
                    new LogInCallback() {


                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseUser user,
                                com.parse.ParseException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if (user != null) {
                                // If user exist and authenticated, send user to Welcome.class
                                if(getFirstRun()){
                                    //user.getObjectId();
                                    Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
                                    ed.putString("user", uname);
                                    ed.putString("pass", pass);
                                    ed.putString("id", user.getObjectId());
                                    ed.commit();

                                    //userid=user.getObjectId();
                                    new GetData().execute();



                                    }else{

                                        Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
                                        ed.putString("user", uname);
                                        ed.putString("pass", pass);
                                        ed.putString("id", user.getObjectId());
                                        ed.commit();
                                        //userid=user.getObjectId();

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();

                                    }

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Error: "+e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

           public  boolean getFirstRun() {
    return mPrefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
}

public void setRunned() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what I am looking for. I know how to use `loginInBackground` and `SharePreferences`. The problem I am facing is how to have the ParseUser object in offline mode in order to `pin` or `saveEventually` with the other entities